# Writing my own 1D-convolution function in Octave

Tags: octave, convolution

We should write our own 1d-convolution, which takes
two time signals as input and returns the convolved time signal as output. The function must be able to handle time signals of any length.

Can someone explain me an easy way for this task? I am a little bit overwhelmed by this task.

I think it is something like this:
If `a = [1 2 3 4 5]` and `b = [-1 -2 -1]` the convolution of both is something like that, isn't it:

```
res = [-1  -4  -8 -12 -16 -14  -5]
```

and to multiply it b is something like:

```
[-1 -2 -1  0  0  0  0
  0 -1 -2 -1  0  0  0
  0  0 -1 -2 -1  0  0
  0  0  0 -1 -2 -1  0
  0  0  0  0 -1 -2 -1]
```

If this is true, how can I create a function that handles all sorts and lengths of input?

I would be very thankful for help.

Comment: Look for `circshift`, you're almost there!

Comment: Thanks I worked it out!